# How to add routelink active to child routes also

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular5

I have a html file as follows.

```
 <ul class="nav side-menu">
                <li routerLinkActive="active">
                  <a routerLink="Teachers/AllTeachers">
                    Teachers 
                  </a>
                </li>
 </ul>
```

In this html file i.e in teacher.component.ts i am redirecting to all teachers component as shown abouve. 
In my app.routing.ts my routes are as follows.

```
    const routes: Routes = [
        { path: '', component: LoginComponentComponent },
        {
            path: 'Dashboard', component: SidebarComponent, canActivate: [OnlyLoggedInGuard],
            children: [
                { path: 'Teachers/AllTeachers', component: AllTeachersComponent},
                { path: 'Teachers/AddTeacher', component: AddTeacherComponent},
]
},
```

now i have to navigate from all teachers to add teacher from all teachers component .I am doing it by clicking another button. But on doing this the routerlink active is not working it is not applying the active class to html.I need to keep the li active as long as it is there in teachers.

Comment: Have you tried `<li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">`?

Comment: No. But what does this exactly do?

Comment: You don't need to set [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" because you don't want to apply active class only when the url exactly matches. https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Comment: No it is not working. In addition to routeLinkActiveOptions do i need to add any other code in app.routing.ts?

Comment: Ok Bahman. But could you please help me out how to solve my problem

Comment: Sure, please check my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample that I created for you:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gx5ovm

I think the trick is moving routerLinkActive="active" to the parent ul instead of li. If you want to have it on the li elements then you have to put routerLinkActive="active" on each one of the li elements.

This is from Angular documentation:

> you can apply the RouterLinkActive directive to an ancestor of a
>   RouterLink.
>
> ```
> <div routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
>   <a routerLink="/user/jim">Jim</a>
>   <a routerLink="/user/bob">Bob</a>
> </div>
> ```

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#description

**UPDATE**:
Is this what you are after?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hvnczx

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhxgdu  is my requirement. When I click Teachers. It is redirecting to AllTeachers and now when i navigate to AddTeacher from AllTeachers then also the teachers should be active because AllTeachers and AddTeachers belong to Teacher.This is my problem. Would you please help.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer you have to put routerLinkActive="active" on the parent element.

Comment: Also can you please clarify what do you mean by " also the teachers should be active"?

Answer (score 1):

[Code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhxgdu) Updated @Bahman code example. Just simply add `routerLinkActive="active"` to routerLink directives.

```
 <ul class="nav side-menu" routerLinkActive="active">
                <li>
                  <a routerLink="/Dashboard/Teachers/AllTeachers" >
                    All Teachers 
                  </a>
                </li>
                ...
 </ul>
```

`routerLinkActive` directive shoulde be together with `routerLink`:

```
   <ul class="nav side-menu" >
                <li>
                  <a routerLink="/Dashboard/Teachers/AllTeachers" routerLinkActive="active">
                    All Teachers 
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a routerLink="/Dashboard/Teachers/AddTeacher" routerLinkActive="active">
                    Add Teachers 
                  </a>
                </li>
 </ul>
```

[CODE EXAMPLE 3](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqgojl)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhxgdu  is my requirement. When I click Teachers. It is redirecting to AllTeachers and now when i navigate to AddTeacher from AllTeachers then also the teachers should be active because AllTeachers and AddTeachers belong to Teacher.This is my problem. Would you please help.

Comment: @roopteja, where is the `Teachers` route?

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative path, to let Angular know it's a relative path, as shown in the code below :

```
              <a routerLink="./AllTeachers">
```